# how to direct spaceline to display "Narrowed" in the mode-line?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, mode-line, spaceline

I'm using Spacemacs, which by default includes `spaceline`. I'd like the mode-line to indicate whether I'm in a narrowed buffer or not. So when I do `org-narrow-to-subtree`, for instance, spaceline could display `Narrowed`.

How can I direct spaceline to display "Narrow" in the mode-line?

Comment: Assuming that `spaceline` processes normal mode-line constructs, you could simply add `%n` to the appropriate variable. See `mode-line-format`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I struggled with this one for quite a while since I wanted the same thing. This is what I did:

[Defining a segment](https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline#defining-a-segment) is quite straight forward and the documentation is very good in that sense. But that's not enough to get it to show what you want. So, first define a segment that can show `Narrowed` when you narrow into some defun, region or whatever:

```
(spaceline-define-segment narrow
  "Display Narrowed when buffer is narrowed."
  (when (buffer-narrowed-p)
    "Narrowed"))
```

The documentation isn't quite clear about how you should insert this new segment into the whole thing. I dug around the code and found out that you can pass new segments when initiating the mode line. Since in my case I'm using `spaceline-spacemacs-theme` it suffices to pass this new segment to that function call:

```
(spaceline-spacemacs-theme 'narrow)
```

Note that it will insert this new segment in the right part of the mode-line, next to the line numbers and columns in my case. If you want to reorder the items you'll have to create a new theme.

The code provided here was enough for me, though.